# Add CogSCi as a migration target

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, migration

Can we please add Cognitive Sciences as a migration target? It only makes sense, since we're bound to have some questions that should probably be migrated there, such as [this](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/1716/why-was-eliza-able-to-induce-delusional-thinking).

Or at least add the 'Not about AI within the scope of the Help Center' things, so that we can VTC/flag as something other than 'Blatantly off-topic'.

Comment: Migration targets usually aren't possible on beta sites, but you can flag it for the moderation to migrate it there manually.

Comment: That makes sense. We can do it after we graduate fully. (Further reading: [Adding stats as a migration target](http://meta.ai.stackexchange.com/a/1104/75).) Also, questions can't be *closed* as "blatantly off-topic"; that reason only appears when *flagging* for closure.

Comment: @BenN That's right, I meant adding the others as flagging options. :/